# Jquery onClick function is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, fetch-api

I am new to react and Im trying to add li to ul dynamically using jquery.
Inside my li I have a sapn with onclick method. When I click the span I want specific method to fire but I get - **Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteMsg is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick**. I've searched for solution but nothing worked. I don't understand what is the problem...

This is my code:

```
    class CoachPage extends React.Component {

      constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state={
          val: []
        }
      }

      handleSend(msg){

        this.state.val.push(msg);
        this.setState({val: []});
    }

    // get all data from db and put in the list
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/')
        .then(function(res) {
          return res.json();
          }).then(function(data){
            var msgs = [data];
             msgs[0].map(function(msg){
                console.log(msg.msgdata);

//Here i add the li's with a sapn and onclick method called "deleteMsg"
                $('#coach-panel-content').append( 
                  (`<li class=myli>${msg.msgdata}<span onclick=deleteMsg('${msg._id}')>X</span></li><hr>`));
             })
          })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }); 
    }

     deleteMsg(item){
        return fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/' + item, {
          method: 'delete'
        }).then(response =>
          response.json().then(json => {
            return json;
          })
        );

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container"  style={{color: '#FFF', textAlign: 'right'}}>
            <h1>Coach Page</h1>
            <AddMsg onSend={this.handleSend.bind(this)}  />
            <Panel header="עדכונים" bsStyle="info" style={{float: 'left', textAlign: 'right', width: '40em'}}>
              <ul id="coach-panel-content">


              </ul>
            </Panel>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default CoachPage;
```

**UPDATE:**

I made all the changes @sandor vasas said and I didn't noticed until now, but when I'm trying to add new msg i get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined". I'm not sure I understand why is that happen..
this is my updated code:

```
class CoachPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state={
      val: []
    }
  }

  handleSend(msg){
    this.state.val.push(msg);
    this.setState({val});
}


// get all data from db and put in the list
componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/')
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( data => this.setState({ val: data }))
    .catch( console.error ); 
}

 deleteMsg(item){
    return fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/' + item, {
      method: 'DELETE'
    }).then(response =>
      response.json()
      .then(json => {
        return json;

      })
    );

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container"  style={{color: '#FFF', textAlign: 'right'}}>
        <h1>Coach Page</h1>
        <AddMsg onSend={this.handleSend.bind(this)}/>
        <Panel header="עדכונים" bsStyle="info" style={{float: 'left', textAlign: 'right', width: '40em'}}>
        <ul id="coach-panel-content">
        { 
          this.state.val.map( (msg, index) =>
            <li key={index} className='myli'>
              {msg.msgdata}
              <span onClick={() => this.deleteMsg(msg._id)}>X</span>
              <hr/>
            </li>
          )
        }
        </ul>
        </Panel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CoachPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest avoiding jQuery for this use case?

React as a view library is suitable enough to handle the display of incoming data using something as simple as state change. Here is some pseudo code to get you started:

```
class CoachPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchYourData.then(data => {
      this.setState({ data: data });
    });
  }

  listItems() {
    return this.state.data.map(msg => {
      return (
        <li class="someClass">
          {msg.msgdata}
          <span onClick={() => (deleteMsg(msg._id)})>X</span>
          <hr />
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // your other code
      <ul id="coach-panel-content">
        {this.state.data.length ? this.listItems() : null}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Upon success of your data fetch, we call `setState` - this will cause a re-render of your component with the new data triggering the injection of list items

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this. In fact, you should use only the React state.

First, your

```
handleSend(msg){
    this.state.val.push(msg);
    this.setState({val: []});
}
```

should be

```
handleSend(msg){
    this.state.val.push(msg);
    this.setState({ val : this.state.val });
}
```

You were pushing an element to the array, but updating the state with an empty array, thereby erasing everything. Just call `setState({ val: val })` or `setState({ val })` (shorthand) to update the state with the same array reference and trigger re-rendering.

Assuming your API returns an array, you can just update the state with it directly, no need for jQuery or making another array of it.

```
componentWillMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/')
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( data => this.setState({ val: data }))
      .catch( console.error ); 
}
```

In render, you output the state's val array:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container"  style={{color: '#FFF', textAlign: 'right'}}>
        <h1>Coach Page</h1>
        <AddMsg onSend={this.handleSend.bind(this)}  />
        <Panel header="עדכונים" bsStyle="info" style={{float: 'left', textAlign: 'right', width: '40em'}}>
          <ul id="coach-panel-content">
          { 
            this.state.val.map( msg =>
              <li class='myli'>
                {msg.msgdata}
                <span onClick={() => this.deleteMsg(msg._id)}>X</span>
              </li>
            )
          }
          </ul>
        </Panel>
      </div>
    );
  }
```